# python get datatype from csv - datetime and time as "2305"

Tags: python, datetime

How can I get the datatypes for datetime and time from a csv file:

```
        with open(dataPath, newline='') as csvData:
             reader = csv.DictReader(csvData, delimiter=';')
             head = next(reader)
             .
             .
```

I have the following csv file:

```
        "...."; "YEAR"; "TIME"; "..." --> head
        "...."; "19.05.2020"; "0050"; "..." --> "0050" means 00:50
        "...."; "12.05.2020"; "2035"; "..." --> "2035" means 20:35
```

I tried it with a function:

```
def convert(value):
    heuristics = [lambda value: datetime.strptime(value, "%d.%m.%Y"), datetime.strptime(value, "%H%D"), int, float]
    for type in heuristics:
        try:
            return type(value)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    # All other heuristics failed it is a string
    return value
```

if I have a value "[1,2,3]" it outputs a valueerror but for this I wrote except ValueError: continue, why does it not continue when this error occure, same with "513165"

thanks

Comment: if you know the format of the column (e.g. "%H%M"), why don't you just parse it, why the complicated function? why not just a try/except that tries different formats if there are more than one?

Comment: because I want to automate the task at the end and it should automatically find the correct data types with the function convert()

Comment: How would the `convert()` function distinguish between a `2035` = 8:35pm and `2035` = the integer that comes after 2034?

Comment: It's a bad, _bad_, __BAD__ idea to catch an exception and just ignore it, unless you know _exactly_ what's causing that exception and you know for sure that it's okay to ignore. Always include the __full__ stack trace of any errors when you're asking for help debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get this working, a few things:

- you'll need a `lambda` for both strptime operations
- `%D` is not a valid strptime directive, I assume you meant `%M`
- don't redefine the built-in `type`
- better catch and print the error, to know what's going on

working example with some tests (don't assume full coverage of *any* possible error though...)

```
def convert(value):
    heuristics = [lambda value: datetime.strptime(value, "%d.%m.%Y"),
                  lambda value: datetime.strptime(value, "%H%M"),
                  int,
                  float]
    for f in heuristics:
        try:
            return f(value)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"encountered error: {e}")
            continue
    # All other heuristics failed it is a string
    return value


for v in ('2355', 'asdf', '12', '3.14', '7.12.2013'):
    print(f"testing '{v}'...")
    result = convert(v)
    print(result, type(result))
```

giving you

```
testing '2355'...
encountered error: time data '2355' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y'
1900-01-01 23:55:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
testing 'asdf'...
encountered error: time data 'asdf' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y'
encountered error: time data 'asdf' does not match format '%H%M'
encountered error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asdf'
encountered error: could not convert string to float: 'asdf'
asdf <class 'str'>
testing '12'...
encountered error: time data '12' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y'
1900-01-01 01:02:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
testing '3.14'...
encountered error: time data '3.14' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y'
encountered error: time data '3.14' does not match format '%H%M'
encountered error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.14'
3.14 <class 'float'>
testing '7.12.2013'...
2013-12-07 00:00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```